# Compare a list of enum values with a single enum

Tags: java

EDIT: Modified the code slightly to use an actual enum and I still see the issue I was referring to.

I have a weird scenario that I haven't seen before, the following code was built on java 6 and before I think but I'm not sure since the code was written back in 2008 and we do not have a way to know on which java version this code was written back then, basically a list of enum values is being compared to a single enum value assuming that the list would at the most only contain one value and the comparison worked fine on java 6 and earlier (I'm not sure about the version) but it fails with java 7

I looked up on the web but could not find any relevant information so was hoping someone could clarify. Here's the example to reproduce the issue that I was referring to -

MODIFIED CODE -

```
public class TestEnum {
    enum Color {
        RED, GREEN, BLUE;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Color> enums = new ArrayList<Color>();
        enums.add(Color.RED);
        if (enums.equals(Color.RED)) {
            System.out.println("Passed the conditional check!!!");
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("Failed the conditional check!!!");
        }
    }
```

Why does the conditional check above fail even though my list of enum values contains only one constant Color.RED and I'm using equals to method to compare? The above mentioned code always prints 'Failed the conditional check'.

Comment: Thank you! But I see other downvotes as well so I wonder if my question is inappropriate because I did a lot of research on the web but could not find any relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing List and Enum with equal which always return false. If you use **contains** instead of **equals**, the condition will work.

```
if (enums.contains(ActionEnum.NONE)) {
```

Comment: That's my question exactly but as per the comment from @GhostCat this check should always work! Equals to should return true even though I'm comparing the list of enums with a single enum constant since this code was written back in 2008 and I'm sure it would have been tested before releasing it to production! I know that I should use contains but how did the above mentioned code work before?

Comment: boolean equals(Object o)
`Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the List interface.`

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this documentation but I want the experts from stack overflow to justify the downvotes to my question as @GhostCat said that it would work and the developer who wrote this code back in 2008 was sure it would work since our code would go through different levels of testing before it gets to production environment! I ponder over the immediate down votes and the first answer to my question!

Answer (score 2):

And to answer the question:

> but now I see that the comparison returns false even though the list contains the enum ActionEnum.NONE.

No, it doesn't. When that inner list contains ActionEnum.NONE, then `true` is returned and method execution stops right there.

The **only** way for this method to return `false` is:

- `getFormats()` returns an empty list OR
- all of the Action objects (retrieved via `getActionEnum()`) are either empty or do not contain ActionEnum.NONE

Nowadays, you could rewrite this to:

```
for (Format f : getFormats()) 
  for (ActionEnum e : f.getActions()) 
    if (e.getActionEnum == ActionEnum.NONE) 
      return true;
return false;
```

Edit: my code assumed that something called ActionEnum would actually be a real enum. But as it isn't in this case, == would not be replaced with e.equals() here!

Regarding the yet-another-update: the other answer is correct: your current code does **someList . equals ( somethingThatIsNotAList )**. That will always return false. You need `enums.contains(someEnum)` instead.

Comment: I wrote a sample code and reproduced the issue that I was referring to where the conditional check fails even though my list contains one enum value which is NONE, I would like to attach the screenshots of the debug mode eclipse inspection window as well, should I edit my question and attach the screenshots or should I add them as a part of the comment?

Comment: Enhanced the question! Thank you @GhostCat

Comment: The code mentioned above in the question always fails the conditional check. Has anyone else been able to reproduce it? I need a justification for the needless downvotes.

Comment: Yes you are right about the fact that this isn't a real enum but its an emulation API of the Java 5 enum language and SDK features, thank you all for the help!

Comment: any thoughts on the latest modification? I used an actual enum but still the equals method returns false, I debugged further and noticed that the equals(Object 0) method in the class AbstractList is being invoked and there's a logic to check if the passed object is an instance of List interface and if its not then false is returned, is my understanding correct?